# Replace an Array to represent as a string - Logic Error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript array in the following format;

```
["One","Two","Three"]
```

I want this to be a string in the following format;

```
('One','Two','Three')
```

I tried the following; but it says `TypeError: arr.replace is not a function` (I guess this is because `arr` is an array)

```
 arr=arr.replace("[","(");
arr=arr.replace("]",")");
```

How can replace the strings `[ " ]` with `( ' )` as described above.

Comment: You want to convert the array in to the string `('One','Two','Three')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.join()`:

```
> var a = ["One","Two","Three"];
> "('" + a.join("','") + "')"
"('One','Two','Three')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot use .replace on Array. You can do the following though

```
var arr = ["One","Two","Three"];
    arr = "('" + arr.join("', '") + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to be a string, not an array instance. <del>Try this</del>:

```
arrStr = arr.toString();
arrStr=arrStr.replace("[","(");
arrStr=arrStr.replace("]",")");
```

**EDIT** I remembered incorrectly, this would not provide the appropriate results... The output would be:

```
One,Two,Three.
```

The recommended solution is posted first by @Blender, joining the array parts together, and adding the required opening and closing brackets...

If you have to solve this with using only replace(), this would get the proper result:

```
arrStr = arr.toString();
arrStr=arrStr.replace(",","','");
arrStr = "('" + arrStr "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to convert your array to string

```
var arr = ["One","Two","Three"]​;
var str = "('"+arr.join("','")+"')";
alert(str);
​
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aa5mF/)